# Adding new elements to a table that has already been saved

Tags: lua, coronasdk

So, I am working on a premium code system where you can input a secret code and if the code is valid, it will reward you based on what code you have used. Pretty simple idea, however, I have some trouble with it.

I have a table with all the codes that looks something like this:

```
GameState.PremiumCodesTable = GameState.PremiumCodesTable or {{code = "X45", value = 30}, {code = "MM4", value = 45}, {code = "B47", value = 100}}
```

Basically, if the game runs for the first time, the `GameState.PremiumCodesTable` will be `nil` and it will create new element in `GameState` table which is this table: `{{code = "X45", value = 30}, {code = "MM4", value = 45}, {code = "B47", value = 100}}`

Now, when the user uses the valid code, it **gets deleted** from the table. Eventually the user will find all the codes, use them and the `GameState.PremiumCodesTable` table will be empty.

Now, I want to update the game and bring in some new codes to find. However, since the `GameState.PremiumCodesTable` is already empty and **saved**, it will always be empty.

How can I add more codes later on?

I have a solution, but I don't like it, so I am asking here. My solution is to add code by code like so:

```
GameState.PremiumCodesTable[1] = GameState.PremiumCodesTable[1] or {code = "X45", value = 30}
GameState.PremiumCodesTable[2] = GameState.PremiumCodesTable[2] or {code = "MM4", value = 45}
GameState.PremiumCodesTable[3] = GameState.PremiumCodesTable[3] or {code = "B47", value = 100}
```

and so on... However, this takes too much space, so I'd like it to have in only **ONE big table** like the one above.

Comment: `table.remove` and `table.insert`. Think about `{x45=30}` or `{x45={type=1, count=2, value=3}}`: insert with simple `table[code]=something`, remove with `table[code]=nil` (or `false` to mark used codes) and checking like `if table[code] then ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the save file to store an array of code strings that have been used, then initialize `PremiumCodesTable` to contain full data for all of the codes. That way, the save file keeps the bare minimum amount of information, and you get maximum freedom to process the save file however you want. (You may need to store the code data in a non-array table to make it easier to access.)

```
GameState.usedCodes = GameState.usedCodes or {}

local PremiumCodesTable = {
  {code = "X45", value = 30},
  {code = "MM4", value = 45},
  {code = "B47", value = 100}
}
```